# RMAN connecting to wrong target

Tags: oracle11g, rman

When I run `rman target / @mydb nocatalog cmdfile=%commands% msglog=%logfile%`, I see `connected to target database: OTHERDB (DBID=3786352837, not open)`.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your target database SID = HR_VMC, to connect this target database issue the following commands to connect it using RMAN

```
export ORACLE_SID = HR_VMC
sqlplus
SQL> connect / as sysdba
SQL> select name from v$database;
```

it shows the HR_VCM
open another terminal and from the comman line issue the following RMAN command

```
RMAN target /
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting environment variable ORACLE_DB to the target database helps the cause.

```
Set ORACLE_SID=mydb
```

StackOverflow and ServerFault seem to suffer from lack of Oracle expertise. Weak.